# junit test для метода

Tags: java, юнит-тесты, junit, scanner

Подскажите пожалуйста, у меня есть метод void product(), который состоит из сканнера и в результате выводит произведение положительных чисел, введенных в консоли, чисел всего три штуки, мне нужно протестировать этот метод, но без входных данных у меня не получается этот метод протестировать, вот код метода. Буду рад, если кто то поможет сделать тест для этого метода.

```
public void product() {
        System.out.print("Please Enter 3 numbers  : ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            numbers[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] > 1) {
                positiveProduct *= numbers[i];
            }
        }
        if (positiveProduct == 1) {
            System.out.println("Не найдено положительных чисел");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Произведение положительных чисел " + positiveProduct);
        }
    }
```

P.S. Или можно как то сделать этот метод с входными данными?

Comment: `Или можно как то сделать этот метод с входными данными?` не можно, а нужно.

Comment: у вас вообще метод непонятно что делает. Попробуйте для начала его назвать так, чтобы по названию сразу было ясно, в чем назначение метода.

Comment: вторым шагом осознайте, что метод не должен содержать и логику и ввод/вывод данных. Разделите это на 2 метода.

Comment: третьим шагом поймите, что метод с вводом/выводом тестировать не надо, а вот метод с логикой будет легко протестировать, если все данные, что методу надо, он получит на входе как параметры и весь результат работы метода он вернет в возращаемом значении.